# What is TupleView and AnyView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Confused between TupleView and AnyView, Can anyone explain in detail TupleView and AnyView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AnyView` is a type-erased `View`. It is necessary for overcoming some of the type system limitations. For example, the following does not compile:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State private var showText: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if showText {
            return Text("This is text.")
        } else {
            return Rectangle()
        }
    }
}
```

This is because `some View` requires that the same concrete `View` type is returned in every possible case. We can't return `Text` in one case and `Rectangle` or whatever else in another.

We can't use `View` (without `some`) either, as protocols with associated types can't be used as a concrete type.

This is where `AnyView` comes to the rescue:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
    
    @State private var showText: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if showText {
            return AnyView(Text("This is text."))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Rectangle())
        }
    }
}
```

In general, you can use `AnyView` whenever you want to hide a concrete type and just return `View`. This is not unique to SwiftUI.  `AnyCollection`, `AnySequence` etc. play the same role.

`TupleView` is a concrete `View` type uses to store multiple `View` values. It's rarely used, mostly by library developers for implementing [view builders](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder), something like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    init<C0, C1>(
        @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> TupleView<(C0, C1)>
    ) where C0: View, C1: View {
        let content = content().value
        // do something with content
    }

    // implement the rest of the view
}
```

`MyView` can now be used with the special syntax, like this:

```
MyView {
  View1()
  View2()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.. I have a swiftUI view returning two different custom views based on a boolean property (part of a class) marked with @StateObject. If it's working for two different custom Views, why not Circle and Text? I tried the code shown above and compilation does fail... Why?