# Returning different SwiftUI views at runtime

Tags: ios, swiftui

A SwiftUI `View` has the following structure:

```
struct MessageView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

According to [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-swiftui-use-some-view-for-its-view-type), the body property is marked `some View` because the exact type of `View` returned is complex and can change after editing the `View`... even adding a modifier changes the type of the `View`.

While `some View` ensures that we don't have to deal with the exact type of `View`, it is still a solid `View` and fills the associated type of the `View` protocol i.e.,  SwiftUI knows that this `View`'s body is returning a `Text` (in this case). At compile time, SwiftUI must know the exact kind of the View returned by the body property.. therefore, the following code doesn't work,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showText: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if showText {
            return Text("This is text.")
        } else {
            return Rectangle()
        }
    }
}
```

because the kind of `View` returned, is not known at compile time. The associated type cannot be inferred by SwiftUI. I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155652/12791298).

But the following code works:

```
struct MessageView: View {
    
    @StateObject 
    var messageStyle: MessageStyle = MessageStyle("Initialzed by MessageView!", fontColour: .blue, fullscreen: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if(!messageStyle.isFullScreen) {
            DefaultMessageView(messageStyle: messageStyle) 
        } else {
            FullScreenMessageView(messageStyle: messageStyle)
        }
    }
}
```

How can this code work? SwiftUI doesn't know which kind of View (DefaultMessageView(_:) or FullScreenMessageView(_:)) is returned at compile time, right? How does the associated type get inferred here?

Comment: This is because the ```body``` of a ```View``` is implicitly a ```ViewBuilder```. If you were to take the ```return``` statements out of your second example, it would work too.

Comment: The last part of Hamish's answer in the dupe target should answer your question.

Comment: See also [`buildEither`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildeither(first:)), which returns a `_ConditionalContent`. *That* is the inferred type.